# Bootstrap the Complexity Index in (Ex)TraMineR?

Tags: r, traminer

I'm computing the Complexity Index using TraMineR.
Does it make sense to use the bootstrap procedure in order to obtain the confidence intervals for the Complexity Indexes? In this case, is there a specific TraMineR command or should I use the classic way? 
Thank you,
Emanuela

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complexity index is a measure of intra-sequence complexity. It is a numeric (i.e. continuous) value. As such, you can use any statistical procedure adapted to continuous values. This includes bootstrap confidence interval, linear regression, ...

TraMineR does not provide a specific command. In R, you can use the "boot" function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is what I was thinking! Thank you for the confirmation!